# Include What You Use wants a forward declaration of a type stored in an array in a template class which results in a field has incomplete type error

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration, iwyu

eI have a template class, similar to the following class.
The behaviour is not that relevant, important is, that it has an array as attribute which stores T and its size depends on the template parameter TCapacity.

```cpp
template <class T, size_t TCapacity>
class MyClass {
  public:
  explicit MyClass() { container_ = std::array<T, TCapacity>(); }
  ~MyClass() = default;
  MyClass(MyClass const& r) = delete;

  MyClass(MyClass&& r) noexcept {
    container_ = std::move(r.container_);
  }

  auto Put(T item) -> void {
    index_ = ++index % TCapacity;
    container_[index_] = item;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] auto Get() -> std::optional<T> {
    auto result = container_[index_];
    return result;
  }

  private:
  std::array<T, TCapacity> container_;
  size_t index_ = 0;
};
```

I use the template class as an attribute in another class, e.g.:

```cpp
class AnotherClass{
  ...
  private:
  MyClass<SomeType, kSize> mc_;
  ...
}
```

As far as I understand, the compiler needs to know how big `SomeType` is to correctly allocate memory.
Thus, I include the corresponding header file for `SomeType` in the file of `AnotherClass`.
IWYU wants me to remove the include of `SomeType` and replace it by a forward declaration of `SomeType`.
Now, the compiler does not know how big `SomeType` is, and throws an `field has incomplete type` error.

I am not sure whether the behaviour of IWYU corresponds to this issue [IWYU#1217](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues/1217) and it can be regarded as a bug, or whether I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

How can I build the template class so that IWYU does not complain?

The proposed solution by 463035818_is_not_an_ai will add unnecessary code to `MyClass`.
What I've learned is, that my initial understanding, that the issue raised by IWYU and its proposed solution is invalid.
As a result, I will add `// IWYU pragma: keep` to the include that causes the IWYU bug.
This IWYU pragma will silence the warning for this specific include.

Comment: The forward declaration alone won't work. Looks like IWYU is wrong.

Comment: in general its not trivial to decide if a template argument must be complete or not (without actually instantiating the template). Yours definitely must be

Comment: I agree with @j6t: The forward declaration alone won't work. _Side note:_ I have been experimenting with modules in several recent projects developed with MSVC. Although, according to this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170) dated 2023-Jun-08,  it is still a preview feature, those programs use `import std` with good success. No more `#include` hassles!

Comment: I have to use IWYU. Although the result it produces makes no sense, the CI/CD pipeline fails due to this issue.

Comment: to silence the diagnostic you can try to add some noop that is recognized by IWYU as needing a complete type. Eg `static_assert(sizeof(SomeType) == sizeof(SomeType))`

Comment: IWYU is not without bugs and false positives/negatives. It's not really a tool to use in a CI pipeline. It's a great tool to run once in a while to clean things up, but everything it says needs to be taken with a grain of salt and evaluated by a knowledgeable human, not just blindly trusted by a CI system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a non-static data member must be complete, so the definition of `AnotherClass` will cause implicit instantiation of `MyClass<SomeType, kSize>`.

Because `MyClass<SomeType, kSize>` has the type `std::array<SomeType, kSize>` for a non-static data member, its instantiation will cause implicit instantiation of `std::array<SomeType, kSize>`.

Now, generally if there is no specific exception, implicit instantiation of a standard library template requires the template arguments to be complete. There is no such exception for `std::array` and it is pretty obvious, as you are also saying, that `std::array` can only be implemented properly in a way that instantiation requires `SomeType` to be complete.

So yes, `SomeType` must be complete before the definition of `AnotherClass` (which is where the point-of-instantiation of the implicitly instantiated class template specializations will be).

One needs to be careful with type completeness for template arguments like this. There is not only a risk of causing compilation errors, but it can easily cause undefined behavior.

If a standard library template specialization is instantiated with an incomplete type as argument where this is not specifically allowed, then the library preconditions are violated and the program has *undefined behavior*.

For an example of a practical manifestation of this UB, when type traits are used by the template, which are generally not allowed to be instantiated with incomplete types, it can easily happen that the compiler will cache a nonsense result of the type trait evaluation for the incomplete type and will then later use the cached result in other places where the type trait is applied to the completed type, resulting in incorrect type trait results and behavior, but no warning or error.

So, neither should IWYU be trusted without verification, nor is trial-and-error suitable.